# Using geom_point with geom_col and faceting

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, facet

I have the below example code that's been melted from a dataframe (this is an example; in reality I have 8 portfolios with 30 tickers per portfolio):

```
Ticker       variable                value   Portfolio
AAPL          Factor_Risk            4.66      US
ABBV          Factor_Risk            1.71     INTL
AAPL          Stock_Specific_Risk    0.21      US
ABBV          Stock_Specific_Risk    0.07     INTL
AAPL          Weight                 4.00      US
ABBV          Weight                 1.66     INTL
```

This also assumes US portfolio is composed of only AAPL and INTL portfolio is composed only of ABBV.  I have some code that allows me to build a stacked bar chart (for risk) and a line (for weight):

```
Raw_Portfolio_Data_melt$Type = factor(ifelse(Raw_Portfolio_Data_melt$variable == "Weight", "Weight", "Risk"),
             levels = c("Weight", "Risk"))

ggplot(Raw_Portfolio_Data_melt, aes(x = Ticker, y = value)) +
  geom_col(data = subset(Raw_Portfolio_Data_melt, variable != "Weight"), aes    (fill = variable)) +
  geom_line(data = subset(Raw_Portfolio_Data_melt, variable == "Weight"), aes   (group = 1, color = variable)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = "black") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Two questions (very new to R and even newer to ggplot)
1.  How can I adjust the line so as to use geom point (basically just have a marker instead of a line) for weight
2. How can I facet on portfolios so that US will be a chart of stocks and INTL will be a chart right underneath US?

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: I answered my own question as it relates to geom_point, but in terms of faceting...based on my understanding, in the example both plots will have both tickers on the x axis because that's the way faceting works.  What if I wanted to plot them underneath each other with a variable x axis (the first one would be only AAPL (for the US portfolio) and the second would be only ABBV (for the INTL portfolio)? Is that possible with faceting or would I need to do this in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that should help. I built dummy data off of what you posted, just so you could see more being plotted on the x-axes.

I used `fct_collapse` from `forcats` (ships with `tidyverse`) to collapse `variable` into Risk or Weight. What you wanted to do with this, I wasn't entirely clear on, so feel free to correct me on that.

For faceting, you tell it what column you want to split on--in your case, `Portfolio`. To get a single column (you said you wanted one below the other), use `ncol = 1`, and to get only x-axis labels that occur in each portfolio, use `scales = "free_x"`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dummy <- tibble(
    Ticker = rep(letters[1:6], each = 3),
    variable = rep(c("Factor_Risk", "Stock_Specific_Risk", "Weight"), times = 6),
    value = runif(18, 0, 1),
    Portfolio = rep(c("US", "INTL"), each = 9)
    ) %>%
    arrange(Ticker, variable, Portfolio) %>%
    mutate(type = as.factor(variable) %>% fct_collapse(Risk = c("Factor_Risk", "Stock_Specific_Risk")))


ggplot(dummy, aes(x = Ticker, y = value)) +
        geom_col(data = . %>% filter(type == "Risk")) +
        geom_point(data = . %>% filter(type != "Risk")) +
        facet_wrap(~ Portfolio, ncol = 1, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-04-30 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Perfection.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, how would I go about closing a question?

Comment: If this answer works, you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: One more question on this...I realized I have too many portfolios than will fit on one page.  The raw dataframe includes everything.  But if I want to still facet by portfolio (with only three plots per page for example) what's the best way to do that?

Comment: I haven't had to do that before, but I believe functions in the `ggforce` package and maybe `cowplot` can do that

Comment: thanks for the response.  I'm actually changing this at the source level (on the input excel sheet i'm grouping these rather than changing the facet prior to the plot).  Thank you!